# Construction of formal systems and generative procedures in a meta-theory

Tags: logic, formal-languages, foundations, philosophy

This question is primarily concerned with the construction of formal systems, what are the necessary assumptions in the meta-theory, and notions of a priori vs a posteriori existence of generative procedures.

Suppose that we are working within the meta-theory consisting of natural language and basic primitive notions dependent upon the philosophical stance taken.

1) Must we necessarily assume that any notion we use to build our formal system, namely a collection of object variables/formal symbols and strings of symbols exist a priori in the meta-theory? Are we necessarily working within a fixed meta-theory background?

2) Often, to accommodate various finitist stances, one builds procedures within a formal system to allow the user to generate on demand, new symbols as object variables. To what extent, must the output strings of these generative procedures exist in the meta-theory a priori? This seems like it could not be true, otherwise one would necessarily have infinitely many symbols in the meta-theory to begin with.

3) Can the notions of "working within a theory/formal system" and having a "procedure to generate object variables on demand" be made more precise? In other words, is it up to interpretation whether we allow the user to truly generate new strings with an algorithm or are they only allowed to use pre-existing objects built into the system?

Comment: You don't need anything more than a finite set of pre-existing symbols to have a countably infinite number of variable symbols. Just use one extra character 
' and let the variables be x, x', x''', x'''', etc. (Or use two symbols if unary makes you sad or you only want logarithmic growth in the size of expressions).

Comment: if your meta-theory consists of natural language, you have all you need: you have symbols, you have procedures to generate and manage syntactical complex entities (string, statements, arguments) and you have natural logic tools to reason about them.

Comment: In other words, I should not be thinking of the meta-theory consisting of natural language as a fixed, pre-existing set theoretic structure which I am treating simply as a repository to take pre-generated symbols and structures from to define a formal system? In particular, it is a dynamical environment which I can interact with, in which I can truly define new procedures and generate new symbols within the meta-theory? More precisely, the main notion I am struggling with can be phrased as a priori vs a posteriori existence of such object variables and strings within the meta-theory.

Comment: Explicitly, to what extent do the output variables x, x', x'', ... of the procedure exist within the meta-theory before defining the formal system to which these object variables belong to?